# Значение предложения изменяется при перестановке запятой

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, смысл

1) Т.Валь заплатите потом, планируйте.

2) Т.Валь заплатите, потом планируйте.

Возник спор, спорщик утверждает что в предложении 1 имеется  в виду, что т. Валя должна сначала заплатить, а потом уже планировать. Я же утверждаю, что если бы имелось в виду это, то в предложении стояла бы запятая, как в предложении 2.

Подскажите, как правильно.

Comment: Т. Валь — обращение? Тогда отделите его запятой.

Comment: Спорщик — любитель поспорить. А у вас, вероятно, подразумевался "участник спора".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все зависит от того, какой смысл вы вкладываете в предложение. Если надо заплатить, а потом планировать, то запятая должна стоять перед словом потом. Т. к.оно относится к глаголу "планировать". Если же смысл таков, что заплатить надо потом,то запятая ставится после "потом". Т. к. в этом случае оно будет относится к глаголу заплатить. Ср.: Заплатите/ потом плантруйте. Заплатите потом/ планируйте. 
.

Answer (score 1):

Смена места запятой может менять смысл предложений и судьбы людей. Вспомним знаменитое "Казнить нельзя помиловать".

Заплатите потом, планируйте = Заплатите потом, планируйте сейчас.
Заплатите, потом планируйте = Заплатите сейчас, потом планируйте.